# Error en la creacion de lista de validacion en excel con vba

Tags: vba

Saludo a todos los integrantes
Me encuentro realizando un archivo en excel para el control de pago a proveedores, en la Hoja1 inserte un buscador que despliega un listbox en el cual se incluyen todas las coincidencias de búsqueda, al dar click en el registro elegido se agregan los datos del proveedor y debería de crearse una lista de validación con el total de sus facturas que se han recibido.
El problema es que al llegar al código para la inserción de la lista de validacion en la hoja de excel me marca el error 1004 "Error definido por la aplicacion o objeto".
el codigo es el siguiente:

```
    Private Sub lisBuscador_Click()
   '
   Dim A As Integer
   Dim I As Integer
   Dim X As Integer
   Dim T As String
   '
   With lisBuscador
      If .ListCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
      I = .List(.ListIndex, 1)
      .Visible = False
      txtBuscador = ""
      X = Hoja1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
      For A = 1 To 5
         Hoja1.Cells(X, A + 1) = Hoja2.Cells(I, A)
      Next
      '  Inserto formulas
      Hoja1.Cells(X, 7).FormulaLocal = "=SUMAR.SI(xRFC,C" & X & ",xTotal)"
      Hoja1.Cells(X, 8).FormulaLocal = "=-SUMAR.SI(xRFC,C" & X & ",xPagos)"
      Hoja1.Cells(X, 9).FormulaLocal = "=G" & X & "+H" & X
        
      With Range("J" & X).Validation
         .Delete
         .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
              AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
              Operator:=xlBetween, _
              Formula1:= _
              "=INDIRECTO(""Fac!G""&COINCIDIR(C5,xRFC,0)&"":G""&COINCIDIR(C5,xRFC,0)+CONTAR.SI(xRFC,C5)-1)"
      End With
      
      '
      Hoja1.Cells(X, 11).FormulaLocal = "=SI.ERROR(BUSCARV(J" & X & ",xDatos,16,0)-BUSCARV(J" & X & ",xDatos,26,0),0)"
      Hoja1.Cells(X, 1).FormulaLocal = "=SI.ERROR(COINCIDIR(J" & X & ",xUUID,0),0)"
      Range(Cells(X, 2), Cells(X, 13)).Select
      With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
         .LineStyle = xlContinuous
         .ThemeColor = 9
         .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
         .Weight = xlThin
      End With
      Hoja1.Cells(X + 1, 1).Select
   End With
   '
End Sub

Lo que intento es introducir el rango donde se encuentran la facturacion del provedor, 
ejemplo; 
=INDIRECTO("Fac!G"&COINCIDIR(C5,xRFC,0)&":G"&COINCIDIR(C5,xRFC,0)+CONTAR.SI(xRFC,C5)-1) 
deberia de poner =INDIRECTO(Fac!G15:G21)
```

Me podrian orientar o indicar si lo estoy escribiendo mal

Muchas gracias por su atencion y respuestas